# How can I decompose a matrix w/ N rows and M columns into N matrices and use slightly different names?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I want to decompose a matrix with N rows and M columns into N matrices with slightly different names. The question is how can I use the name as an input to load the matrix, and then assign that to those N matrices?

```
function bestfunc(myname)
data = load(myname, '-mat')
N = length(data)
for i=1:N;
myname = data(i,1)
filename = ['myname_', num2str(i), 'mat']
save(filename, 'myname')
end
```

In this way I want to prevent to change the function and use a name as an input to name different matrices with distinct names (which is slightly different from the input).

Comment: If `myname` is a string, you don't need to put quotes around it when generating the `filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different variable with the same name `myname`. The first one is the input of the function and then you make a new variable which is not a string inside the function.

1. pass the file name without the extension and add the `.mat` inside the function.
2. read the file and open the for-loop
3. for each chunk of data create a new file name. Use the `fname + '_' + i + '.mat'`
4. for a filename such as `myfile` you will get `myfile_1.mat`,...,`myfile_12.mat`

You also forgot the `.` before the `mat` the rest works fine:

```
function bestfunc(fname)  %<-- pass the filename without the extension
ffname = [fname '.mat'];  %<-- add the extenstion
data = load(ffname);      %<-- load the file
N = length(data);
for i=1:N
    myname = data(i,1);   %<-- load each row
    filename = [fname, '_' num2str(i), '.mat'];  % <-- the dot
    save(filename, 'myname');
end
```

A sample run:

```
>> main('myfile')


filename =

myfile_1.mat


filename =

myfile_2.mat
```